# How to get the "routed" url, in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

Let's say I added a route (using `addRoute()` function) that maps this
`/user_info.php?id=2`
to
`/user/2`

How to:

1. Change the url to `/user/2` in the address bar? (when the user types `user_info.php?id=2`)
2. In my helper functions, how to get `/user/2` and not `/user_info.php?id=2` (which I can get using `$_SERVER` variable)

Answer (score 0):

1) Simply don't point them at the query-version of your page and you don't have to worry about it.

2) Isn't that simply REQUEST_URI or PHP_SELF?

Comment: there are legacy urls that I need to map, so can't avoid it.  REQUEST_URI would only give me user_info.php?id=2 and not /user/2

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure REQUEST_URI gives you the part Apache gets, not the rewritten part. **-edit-** Checked, it does.

Comment: but I need the re-written part :(

Comment: I thought you needed the /user/2 part? If you need the rewritten part, simply get $_GET and make a NVP string - that's really easy: `$str = ''; foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { $str .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value).'&'; } $str = substr($str, 0, -1);`